# Problema duplicidad de numero correlativo Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-7

tengo un problema al asignar correlativos a mis registros
tengo una tabla con los campos serie y el numero correlativo, mencionar que cada serie tiene su propio correlativo, dicho eso no puedo poner el campo correlativo como único en bd.

el sistema coge el correlativo del ultimo registro y lo suma +1, pero cuando muchas personas dan clic al mismo tiempo, el sistema hace que el correlativo de duplique, ya que la diferencia fue por segundos.

alguna idea de como solucionar este problema, mencionar que esta por transaccion.

Comment: Y en tu tabla ese campo tiene el atributo de ser `unique`?, ese podría ser un camino para que no se dupliquen datos

Comment: Hola, como mencione no puedo ponerlo unico, porque aparte de correlativo tiene una serie, eso quiere decir que puede haber el mismo correlativo pero en diferente serie ejemplo
serie 100 - correlativo 1 serie 100 - correlativo 2
serie 200 - correlativo 1

Comment: Precisamente, el hecho de que tenga un número al final hace que el recurso sea único, por eso yo considero que si es viable usar `unique`

Comment: Entonces, como seria el campo unique pero que dependa de la columna serie?
yo tambien pense en unique, pero no veo la forma de agregarlo dependiendo de otra columna

Comment: Puedes establecer un índice único de varias columnas, no obstante el problema de concurrencia seguirá existiendo solo que en lugar de insertar duplicados obtendrás un error.